# Fonts in MAUI custom controls

Tags: dll, font-awesome, maui, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a MAUI custom control that uses Font Awesome in a separate project (library). I'm not sure where I have to register the font or it must be deployed separately from dll/project and registered in main app? I cannot be sure that applications who uses my dll has FA installed...

Searched documentation & google with no result

Comment: Do you mean you want to consume your Font Awesome in a separate class library project? If so, you may need to create a FontResource class and statically initialize a list of font resources and then configure it by using `ConfigureFonts` in your MauiProgram.cs, see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/10762 for more details.